# How can I set other temlates/view for posts in specific category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have single.php file and it set the default template for my posts.

How can I set more views/templates for posts in specific category?

I saw that there are plugins, but plugins aren't up to date.

Can i do this without any plugins? I know how I can do this for pages but no for posts.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.

look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

```
if (in_category('myCategory')) {
    // show template for this category post
} elseif ( in_category('2ndMyCategory')) {
    // show template for 2nd category post
} else {
    // show template for deafault post
}
```

Try this, I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get posts with a certain category by modifying your query, adding `'category_name' => 'insertcategoryname',`.